# What is this glassware between flask and condenser to collect liquid?

Tags: equipment, identification, distillation

I've been trying to identify this piece of glassware for ages now. I've been combing the internet and can't seem find anything similar. It looks like some kind of adapter/collecter/trap that sits on the pot and the condenser goes on top.

[image: looks like some kind of adapter that sits on the pot and the condenser goes on top]

Comment: The picture looks like an upscaled screenshot of a video hosted on YouTube. Would you mind sharing the URL? So far from the look of it I'd say it's a custom-made piece of glassware, but the context might help.

Comment: thank you.  i will find the video and post a link of it. regards, james

Comment: It is a collector indeed. For small amount of distilled target

Answer (score 2):

This glassware is used to separate /remove the light phase from a biphasic (immiscible) liquid mixture.  This can be used primarily to enhance liquid-liquid extraction from the light phase to the denser phase. As a mixed distillate collects,  the denser phase will eventually siphon back through the side-arm to the flask below and the light phase remains in the collector.